# boto dynamodb2: Can I query a table using range key only?

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

In one of my python application, I am using boto and I want to query a dynamodb table using range key only. I don't want to use scan.

**Schema for ratings table**

```
ratings = Table.create('ratings', schema=[
    HashKey('user_id', data_type=NUMBER),
    RangeKey('photo_id', data_type=NUMBER)
], throughput={
    'read': 5,
    'write': 15,
}, indexes = [
    AllIndex('rating_allindex', parts=[
        HashKey('user_id', data_type=NUMBER),
        RangeKey('photo_id', data_type=NUMBER)
    ])
])


from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
ratings = Table('ratings')
# photo_id is range_key and user_id is hash_key
ratings_list = ratings.query(photo_id__eq=1)
```

On doing so, I get this error `Query condition missed key schema element user_id`. 
Again, I thought I could give a filter condition to my hash_key

```
ratings_list = ratings.query(user_id__gte=1, photo_id__eq=1)
```

But it showed the error, `Query key condition not supported`. I suppose only the filter __eq is allowed with hash_key. How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: Can you show the schema and specify which ones are the lower secondary indexes?

Comment: I have added the schema for ratings table showing the lower secondary indexes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using a [Query](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb.html#boto.dynamodb.layer1.Layer1.query) operation on DynamoDB you must supply **one** hash key, it is not defined as part of the range_key_conditions as you can see in the documentation - so you will have to use user_id_eq as you already figured out.

If you need to get rows from more than one hash key in one API call, you must use Scan (you can fetch multiple rows using batchGet but this is irrelevant to your scenario)

P.s, it appears your secondary index is the same as the Range key, is that a mistake?

Comment: This was super-helpful to me! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 6):

The behavior you want can be achieved using a [global secondary index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) that uses `photo_id` as a hash key.

Answer (score 1):

In AWS SDKv2 you can scan table using AWSDynamoDBScanExpression, eg. iOS:

```
 AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
 AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];
 scanExpression.exclusiveStartKey = nil;
 scanExpression.limit = @20;
 [[[dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[DDBTableRow class]
                   expression:scanExpression]
   continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {...}
```

If you need a condition can use AWSDynamoDBCondition:

```
 AWSDynamoDBCondition *condition = [AWSDynamoDBCondition new];
 AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue *attribute = [AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue new];
 attribute.N = @"400";
 condition.attributeValueList = @[attribute];
 condition.comparisonOperator = AWSDynamoDBComparisonOperatorEQ;
 scanExpression.scanFilter = @{@"latitude": condition};
```

Comment: I got this done correctly for one condition as a part of `scanFilter`. What if I want to have more than one conditions? I tried to add another key-value pair for `scanExpression.scanFilter` but no success. Any comment/suggestion?

Comment: This is not python.

Comment: OP requested a query specifically. This is a scan. They are different operations in DynamoDB. In particular, the "read cost" of a scan is calculated _before_ the filter is applied, but a query applies range key conditions _before_ calculating cost. Because of this, it's generally preferable to use Queries whenever possible, and to avoid Scans unless absolutely necessary: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html