# Illegal query expression: No hash key condition is found in the query in AWS Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have table in AWS mobile hub and I am using the following model for it

```
public class UserstopcoreDO {
    private String _userId;
    private String _usertoplevel;
    private String _usertopscore;
    private String _username;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "userId")
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "userId")
    public String getUserId() {
        return _userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(final String _userId) {
        this._userId = _userId;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "usertoplevel")
    public String getUsertoplevel() {
        return _usertoplevel;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "username")
    public String getUsername() {
        return _username;
    }

    public void setUsername(final String _username) {
        this._username = _username;
    }

    public void setUsertoplevel(final String _usertoplevel) {
        this._usertoplevel = _usertoplevel;
    }

    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "usertopscore", globalSecondaryIndexName = "usertopscore")
    public String getUsertopscore() {
        return _usertopscore;
    }

    public void setUsertopscore(final String _usertopscore) {
        this._usertopscore = _usertopscore;
    }

}
```

In the table, I have 1500+ records and now I want to fetch Top 10 records from it so for that I write the below query

```
final DynamoDBQueryExpression<UserstopcoreDO> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<>();
            queryExpression.withLimit(10);
            queryExpression.setScanIndexForward(false);
            final PaginatedQueryList<UserstopcoreDO> results = mapper.query(UserstopcoreDO.class, queryExpression);
            Iterator<UserstopcoreDO> resultsIterator = results.iterator();
            if (resultsIterator.hasNext()) {
                final UserstopcoreDO item = resultsIterator.next();
                try {
                    Log.d("Item :",item.getUsertopscore());
                } catch (final AmazonClientException ex) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed deleting item : " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                }
            }
```

But when I run the code it gives me an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal query expression: No hash key condition is found in the query
```

but in my condition, I did not need any condition because I want to fetch top 10 records instead of one specific record. So how to handle that condition ?

Comment: It sounds like you want to do a `scan` instead of a `query`.

Comment: so should i used scan for that purpose or i can solve it by using query ?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to "query" DynamoDB without specifying *all* HashKeys, use a Scan instead, i.e. DynamoDBScanExpression.  You probably also want to change your "usertopscore" to be a RangeKey instead of a HashKey.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html every DynamoDBQueryExpression *requires* *all* the Hash Keys be set.

Also see [boto dynamodb2: Can I query a table using range key only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450479/boto-dynamodb2-can-i-query-a-table-using-range-key-only)

Answer (score 5):

Please set the hash key in the query expression. Below is the example of query expression for main table and GSI (need to set the index name).

**Querying the main table:-**

Set the hash key value of the table.

```
UserstopcoreDO hashKeyObject = new UserstopcoreDO();
hashKeyObject.setUserId("1");

DynamoDBQueryExpression<UserstopcoreDO> queryExpressionForMainTable = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<UserstopcoreDO>()
    .withHashKeyValues(hashKeyObject);
```

**Querying the Index:-**

Set the index name and hash key value of the index.

```
UserstopcoreDO hashIndexKeyObject = new UserstopcoreDO();
    hashIndexKeyObject.setUsertoplevel("100");

DynamoDBQueryExpression<UserstopcoreDO> queryExpressionForGsi = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<UserstopcoreDO>()
            .withHashKeyValues(hashIndexKeyObject).withIndexName("usertopscore");
```

**GSI attributes in mapper:-**

```
@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "usertoplevel",  globalSecondaryIndexName = "usertopscore")
public String getUsertoplevel() {
    return _usertoplevel;
}

@DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(attributeName = "usertopscore", globalSecondaryIndexName = "usertopscore")
public String getUsertopscore() {
    return _usertopscore;
}
```

Comment: I set the hast key and it did not return the result because i do not have record with the id 1 so i want to get top 10 results

Comment: If you have hash key with 10 or more records, you would get 10 records. Actually, I see a problem in your design. In your yesterday SO question, you mentioned that GSI has usertoplevel is Partition key and usertopscore as Sort Key. However, usertoplevel is not defined as hash key in the mapper. Not sure what you have now.

Comment: I just create the table in mobile hub in AWS and download the source code now what should i change in order to get the desired result mean top 10 records

Comment: and  globalSecondaryIndexName = "usertopscore" is defined in the mapper and I do not know where i am doing wrong

Comment: what is the hash key and sort key attributes of gsi?  usertoplevel is Partition key and usertopscore as Sort Key?

Comment: Partition Key is usertoplevel and Sort Key is usertopscore

Comment: Change the getter for index hash key and sort key as updated in my answer. Then, set the value for usertoplevel. You will get the top 10 records for the usertoplevel (i.e. hashIndexKeyObject.setUsertoplevel("some value");).

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help i will update and will let you know

Comment: if I set the hashIndexKeyObject.setUsertoplevel("50"); so does it mean that it will only take recodes of user who level is 50 ?

Comment: but I want the top 10 user out of 15000+ users

Comment: If you want to get the usertopscore across the table, you can't achieve using DynamoDB API. The query API works for the single hash key. The scan API doesn't have ScanIndexForward. One option is to copy the data to Hive and run the queries. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.CopyingData.html

Comment: Thanks. But the thing is I want to display on the app the top 10 users so if we can not use DynamoDB API to do that so it means it is not possible?